# Circumference with line intersection

Tags: geometry

How to get the circle $\rho $ from the circumference as a function of the angle $\theta$ formed between a secant line r and the origin $O$? The center of the circumference is given by the ordinate $ (\alpha, \beta)$, and $b$ and $a$ are the projections on the x and y axis, respectively, of the intersection point $P$ of the line r with the circumference edge.

[image]

Comment: Write a cos/sin around the center and calculate $\theta$

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see whether I understood you correctly. Given coordinates $(\alpha,\beta)$ of the center and $(b,a)$ of a point on the circumference of the circle, you want to compute the circle radius $\rho$? In that case I'd use Pythagoras:

$$\rho=\sqrt{(b-\alpha)^2+(a-\beta)^2}$$

But $\theta$ doesn't really come into play here: if you know the point $P=(b,a)$ then you know $\theta$ implicitly. And if you don't have coordinates of $P$ then you have no information about the size of the circle. If you had just $a$ or just $b$, then $\theta$ would become relevant, but I don't see that indicated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$  \tan \theta = \frac {a}{b}$$

you should either give $ (a,b)$ or $\theta$ as independent parameters but not both in your question. ( so as not to be redundant ).

Assuming that you had removed $\theta$ ... as MvG mentions,

$$\rho=\sqrt{(b-\alpha)^2+(a-\beta)^2}$$

However assuming that you removed $(a,b)$ and retained polar angle $\theta$ only, then we *cannot even construct* the scene. The radius $\rho $ cannot be determined, some possibilities ( radii red, blue) are shown below.

[image: Indetrminate Qn]